# in Karate DSL, a '?' in the Given path variable is being converted to a '%' in the request message, how do I resolve this?

Tags: rest, cucumber, karate

In **Karate DSL**, I have the following scenario:

> Feature: Test
>
> Background:
>   * url baseUrl
>
> Scenario: Test
>
> Given path 'serviceRequests/tasks?view=short&page=1&size=25

With **GET** method I get a status as 200

I am getting a response of **404** because this is what Karate is converting the path variable a below. Notice the 'tasks?' string becomes 'tasks%'. Why is this happening and what can I do to resolve it?

GET http://ver-01-shared-services-service-request-service.ver.cloud.ds.gehc.net/serviceRequest/v1/serviceRequests/tasks**%**3Fview=short&page=1&size=25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the proper way to set parameters:

```
Given path 'serviceRequests', 'tasks'
And param view = 'short'
And param page = 1
And size = 25
When method get
Then status 200
```